# Tratamiento de inconsistencias de formato en variable de tiempo al Importar datos en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un conjunto de datos en R donde una variable de horas ha sido importada como texto, esto debido a que, al no especificar que se importe como texto, muchas observaciones se convierten en NAs. Sin embargo, he encontrado que la variable de horas tiene un formato inconsistente. Algunas filas tienen valores numéricos (por ejemplo, 0.24962962962962965), mientras que otras filas tienen el formato HH:MM:SS (por ejemplo, 07:19:52). Mi objetivo es convertir esta variable en un formato de hora consistente en R.

¿Cómo puedo abordar esta situación y convertir la variable de horas en un formato HH:MM:SS consistente para todo el conjunto de datos?

He intentado algunos enfoques utilizando operaciones matemáticas y funciones de conversión, pero no estoy seguro de cómo manejar los valores numéricos y los formatos de tiempo en una sola columna.

adjunto unos datos simplificados para este caso:

```
datos_texto <- c("0.24962962962962965", "07:19:52", "0.123456789", "10:45:30", "0.567891234")
```

Agradecería mucho cualquier consejo o ejemplo de código que pueda ayudarme a resolver este problema y obtener una variable de horas en el formato deseado.

¡Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la relación entre el valor `0.24962962962962965` y una hora determinada? Si tuviera que suponer, imagino que representa el porcentaje de un día, pero estaría bueno que lo aclares